# Jquery on input change Check the first atChar(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to check the first character of a numerical input on change 
for a cc input and on change add the amex, visa, master or discover logo
amex starts with a 3, visa 4, master card 5 ds 6

I saw it done on an airline's website it looked sick 
they didn't have to ask the customer their card type

It would be awesome if I can do that with the Zip code for the city and state as well

if i try and do .val() on this is wont give it to me

not working so well for me now here is what i got so far

```
 var input = document.form.numInput;
 $(input).change(function(){
       if($(this).val().charAt(0) == 3){
         $('.amexlogo').show();  
       }else if($(this).val().charAt(0) == 4){
         $('.visalogo').show();  
       }else if($(this).val().charAt(0) == 5){
         $('.masterlogo').show();  
       }else if($(this).val().charAt(0) == 6){
         $('.discoverlogo').show();  
       }else{
         $('.invalid').show();  
       }
 });
```

This is what i thought the code should look like but in the JS console i cant even get the change event to

```
       console.log(this.val());
```

all it's telling me is

```
       Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Many thanks guys

Comment: Well, a rudimentary test shows that it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/0qmw8f20/ (admittedly I had to change `document.form.numInput` to `document.forms[0].numInput`, but that was in response to an entirely different error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numInput' of undefined`) than you report).

Comment: Thanks David 

I kept fiddling with it  and got it to work. I think my chrome js console bugged out when i made some errors

Answer (score 0):

As you may have multiple forms in your page you must refer to any particular form with it's `name` or by `indexing` it.

```
var input = document.forms[0].numInput;
```

Update your code as follows,

```
var input = document.forms[0].numInput;
 $(input).change(function(){
       if($(this).val().charAt(0) == 3){
         $('.amexlogo').show();  
       }else if($(this).val().charAt(0) == 4){
         $('.visalogo').show();  
       }else if($(this).val().charAt(0) == 5){
         $('.masterlogo').show();  
       }else if($(this).val().charAt(0) == 6){
         $('.discoverlogo').show();  
       }else{
         $('.invalid').show();  
       }
 });
```